# MySQL SUM returns result for all rows when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I need to get sum of value based on group by selected, I am getting all value sum instead, I am trying this way.

Database

```
|    ip      |  date    | value |
| 1698170033 | 19032016 | 1000  |
| 1698170034 | 19032016 | 1000  |
| 1698170033 | 19032016 | 1000  |
| 1698170033 | 20032016 | 1000  |
| 1698170034 | 20032016 | 1000  |
| 1698170035 | 20032016 | 1000  |
| 1698170036 | 20032016 | 1000  |
| 1698170034 | 20032016 | 1000  |
```

MySQl

```
SELECT 
`date`, `ip`, SUM(`value`)
FROM `stats`.`stats`    
GROUP BY `date`, `ip`
```

This gives result as

```
| 1698170033 | 19032016 | 2000 |
| 1698170034 | 19032016 | 2000 |
| 1698170033 | 20032016 | 1000 |
| 1698170034 | 20032016 | 1000 |
| 1698170035 | 20032016 | 1000 |
| 1698170036 | 20032016 | 1000 |
```

Expected result

```
| 1698170033 | 19032016 | 1000 |
| 1698170034 | 19032016 | 1000 |
| 1698170033 | 20032016 | 1000 |
| 1698170034 | 20032016 | 1000 |
| 1698170035 | 20032016 | 1000 |
| 1698170036 | 20032016 | 1000 |
```

Please suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Is this all the query?

Comment: @sagi yes thats all the query for testing purpose

Comment: Why do you use SUM function if you do not want sum in the result?

Comment: try reverting your group by. instead `GROUP BY date, ip` ... try `GROUP BY ip,date`

Comment: @Rahul What would that help? Tallboy try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you either want an average, or just one of the values so:

```
  SELECT `date`, `ip`, AVG(`value`)
  FROM `stats`.`stats`
  GROUP BY `date`, `ip`
```

Or :

```
  SELECT `date`, `ip`, max(`value`)
  FROM `stats`.`stats`
  GROUP BY `date`, `ip`
```

Or you want to distinct the output:

```
  SELECT distinct `date`, `ip`, `value`
  FROM `stats`.`stats`
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks